# Why is this question closed?

Tags: discussion

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/29901/where-in-nolan-chart-are-indonesian-politicians-jokowi-prabowo-ahok-surya-pal

I asked where in Nolan chart are Indonesian politicians. Some says they cannot be answered objectively.

Are they even indonesians?

Do they know?

Some even suggest that Jokowi is Liberal and Prabowo is statist. I would guess the same thing. That is a reasonably objective answers.

I my self would guess that the liberal in Indonesia is similar with conservatives in US. Almost no body in Indonesia as liberal as someone that wants same sex marriage.

So if the nolan chart is drawn bigger, typical Indonesian will be on upper left of typical americans.

I notice that Prabowo's voter are statist and yet want wealth distribution. So they're actually  muslims that want the chinese to pay native indonesians through some racist policies. This seems to be similar to American' far right.

Most Jokowi supporter seems to be closer to American centrist.

But that's my guess. Others may have other guesses and I would love to listen to them.

Answer (score 4):

The question was just auto-deleted by the Community bot because it was closed, had no answers and was not edited for 10 days. For those who can not yet view deleted questions, here is what it reads:

> **Where in Nolan Chart are Indonesian politicians Jokowi, Prabowo, Ahok, Surya Paloh, Mega?**
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nolan_Chart
>
> Based on known evidence, where are the listed Indonesian politicians on Nolan Chart?
>
> Tags: [libertarianism] [indonesia] [political-alignment]

The first problem with this question is that the Nolan chart is a subjective interpretation of a person's political stance. First, it's subjective how you interpret different viewpoints. Is "hate speech must be punished" an authoritarian or libertarian position? And even if you can come to a clear conclusion on every issue, you then have to decide how you rate people when they have views which fall on different sides of the spectrum. When someone says "legalize all drugs but censor all nudity" is that person a libertarian or an authoritarian? Do you have some point system? How do you decide which views score how many points? Is it relevant how much energy they invest into fighting for different issues? How do you quantify that?

This makes this question **primarily opinon-based**.

The second problem is that it asks not one question but five questions:

1. Where is Jokowi on the political spectrum?
2. Where is Prabowo on the political spectrum?
3. Where is Ahok on the political spectrum?
4. Where is Surya Paloh on the political spectrum?
5. Where is Mega on the political spectrum?

Someone who is very familiar with one of these politicians (and willing to step into this minefield of subjectivity) might be able to provide an answer for one of these politicians. But it will be difficult to find someone who can answer properly for *all five*. Now you might say "no problem, let 5 different experts post 5 different answers, then". But that's not how Stack Exchange works. We are looking for *one* top answer which *completely* answers the question.

Further you would have to look at the whole spectrum of political opinions of the person to rate them properly. You are demanding quite a lot of work from the community. This makes the question **too broad**.

My recommendation if you want to know more about the political views of Indonesian politicians would be to:

1. Identify a specific issue which is important to you
2. Ask for the stance of one specific politician at a time

Comment: I see. I understand that nolan chart may be subjective. However, there are many objective part. Hate speech laws is authoritarian. That means government decides what counts as "hate speech". Those who wants to legalize drugs almost always want to legalize nudity. In fact, I think support for 2 stances will have high correlation. Is it?

Comment: I saw similar chart for US politican https://www.zerohedge.com/sites/default/files/images/user3303/imageroot/2013/03/20130315_GTL11_0.jpg I basically want a similar chart for Indonesians. A good answer doesn't have to answer all. If someone knows Jokowi that's good enough.

Comment: Basically it asks which politicians are where? If people knows one or two it's good enough. Again, my mistake is probably I didn't realize that there are few Indonesians herre

Comment: @J.Chang The chart you posted above is *very* opinionated. The choice of portrait pictures alone should make that obvious. It tells you more about the opinions of the person who made the chart than about the opinions of the people depicted in it.